# Installing python package 'processing'

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm new to python and pycharm and getting an error installing the `processing` package. Other packages have installed successfully. I'm been using PyCharm's package installer. However when I type `pip install processing` at the command line I also get an error. My version of PyCharm is 2022.1. Command output from PyCharm is:

```
Collecting processing
  Using cached processing-0.52.zip (178 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Ã— python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  â”‚ exit code: 1
  â•°â”€> [7 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\valle\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-46p1xcde\processing_62a3decf9c0a4eb2b7692c0f8530931b\setup.py", line 12
          raise ValueError, 'Versions of Python before 2.4 are not supported'
                          ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Ã— Encountered error while generating package metadata.
â•°â”€> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.3; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.5\bin\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That package is 14 years old – it's from 2008 – and it's Python 2 only.

You can't install it on Python 3, which is what you (or your QGIS) is running.

Chances are you shouldn't be trying to install it either.

Comment: Thx. I was targetting the wrong library. I should've written `from qgis import processing`.